# Email app Component

Tags: joomla

> Please, anyone can help me finding component for **email app functionality in joomla 3.0**
>   which can include Inbox,send mail box,drafts etc.
>
> such as gmail,thunderbird etc

Answer (score 1):

Roundcube is based on php and can be hosted on a subdomain. [Roundube Website](http://roundcube.net/)

Joomla itself doesn't have webmail as you would need a mailserver which can only be achieved by MX records.

You'll need mail hosting too or run your own mailserver.

Comment: **no problem** its fine, just helping